# How to adjust the sound volume in small increments in Mac OS 10.7 (Lion)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, audio, osx-lion

I use a Macbook that has dedicated sound volume buttons (<kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>).

In Mac OS 10.6 I was able to adjust the sound volume in smaller increments (1/4th of a square) by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Up/Down</kbd>.

This stopped working after the update to 10.7. Any ideas?

Comment: Given that this feature was added in 10.7.4, it'd probably be useful to accept [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/314661/how-to-adjust-the-sound-volume-in-small-increments-in-mac-os-10-7-lion#439738) instead of the current one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are referring to: [Use fine-grain volume control in 10.5](http://www.macworld.com/article/131817/2008/01/volctrl.html)

[Looks like](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1192627) the issue is common. And someone here confirmed this [feature is gone with Lion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3197651?tstart=0):

> Jul 21, 2011 9:09 PM (in response to azoolkool)
>   The option is gone with Lion, sorry.

Here is a [list of some other bugs](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1106318&page=6) you might want to check out.

Comment: Technically, that's not really an answer. The question still is how to change it. They might have only removed the feature from the front-end (and I'm pretty confident about that).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping someone might know some sort of setting that I could change to reactivate this feature, but apparently it is gone.

Answer (score 6):

This shortcut was added again in 10.7.4, so you'll get this feature back once you update your OS.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is far less convenient than before, but it is a workaround.

You can do precise volume adjustment with AppleScript, controlled on a scale of 0 thru 100.

```
set volume output volume 0 --mute
set volume output volume 100 --100%
set volume output volume 27 --27%
```

You can get the current volume (also 0 thru 100):

```
set currentVolume to output volume of (get volume settings)
```

So, you can write a little script to increment the volume by 2% (approximately what one quarter square used to be):

```
set currentVolume to output volume of (get volume settings)
set volume output volume (currentVolume + 2)
```

You can make one for decrementing by changing that plus sign to a minus sign.

You can save this as a script or app, and bind it to a mouse or keyboard button (if your driver lets you), give it a keyboard shortcut (as a Service or with another app), or put it in your menu bar (with an app like FastScripts).

Answer (score 2):

Feature is back in Mountain Lion. <kbd>Shift/Option</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>Shift/Option</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> will adjust it by a fraction increments.

Comment: To be clear you want <kbd>Fn + Opt + Shift + F11/F12</kbd>.